# WSO2 4.0.0 Could not write JSON stream / Error getting GZIP output stream

Tags: json, nginx, wso2, gzip

**I use two WSO2 Api Manager v4.0.0 nodes inside a private network :**

- reverse is the Nginx node that proxy requests to destination ports as a gateway/entrypoint
- apim-bo is the WSO2 control-plane. It hosts devportal/publisher and is the key manager. IP 192.168.0.6, WSO2 listen on port 9443, domain apimbo.mysite.com
- apim-gw is the WSO2 gateway worker used to handle requests. IP 192.168.0.5, WSO2 listen on port 8243, domain apim.mysite.com
- api is the application, a REST Api written in php. It returns json responses. So basically any request hits Nginx proxy then WSO2 gateway, then Nginx proxy again to my application.
- I use a wildcard certificate shared between all nodes

**I have many 499 errors on the Nginx side meaning (I assume) my WSO2 gateway often takes more than 90s to answer :**

> [ClientIP] - - [20/Jan/2023:00:05:54 +0000] "GET /my/api/route
> HTTP/1.1" 499 0 "https://apim.mysite.com/route" [ClientUserAgent];
> [ClientReferer]" "-"

**In the meantime, I'm not sure if my application is hit when it happends, but it answers to a similar request just a few seconds before. Nothing suspicious in my PHP logs :**

> [ClientIP] - - [20/Jan/2023:00:05:51 +0000] "GET /my/api/route
> HTTP/1.1" 200 129933 "https://apim.mysite.com/route"
> "[ClientUserAgent]" "[ClientReferer]"

**The 499 error seems related to a "Could not write JSON stream" error on the gateway side :**

> 2023-01-20T00:05:54,566 [-] [HTTPS-Listener I/O dispatcher-8]  WARN
> SourceHandler I/O error (Probably the connection was closed by the
> remote party):Broken pipe
>
> 2023-01-20T00:05:54,566 [-] [PassThroughMessageProcessor-138] ERROR JsonUtil #writeJsonStream. Could not write JSON stream. MessageID: urn:uuid:4cdd8754-5ff3-46b0-99b4-72167ee4d92f. Error>> Consumer error or stale connection has occurred.
>
> 2023-01-20T00:05:54,567 [-] [PassThroughMessageProcessor-138] ERROR GzipMessageFormatterDecorator Error getting GZIP output stream org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: Could not write JSON stream.
> at org.apache.synapse.commons.json.JsonUtil.writeAsJson(JsonUtil.java:400) ~[synapse-
> commons_2.1.7.wso2v227.jar:?]     at
> org.apache.synapse.commons.json.JsonStreamFormatter.writeTo(JsonStreamFormatter.java:77)
> ~[synapse-commons_2.1.7.wso2v227.jar:?]   at
> org.apache.synapse.transport.nhttp.util.GzipMessageFormatterDecorator.writeTo(GzipMessageFormatterDecorator.java:66)
> [synapse-nhttp-transport_2.1.7.wso2v227.jar:?]    at
> org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.PassThroughHttpSender.submitResponse(PassThroughHttpSender.java:594)
> [synapse-nhttp-transport_2.1.7.wso2v227.jar:?]    at
> org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.PassThroughHttpSender.invoke(PassThroughHttpSender.java:290)
> [synapse-nhttp-transport_2.1.7.wso2v227.jar:?]    at
> org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.send(AxisEngine.java:442)
> [axis2_1.6.1.wso2v63.jar:?]   at
> org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2Sender.sendBack(Axis2Sender.java:213)
> [synapse-core_2.1.7.wso2v227.jar:2.1.7-wso2v227]  at
> org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2SynapseEnvironment.send(Axis2SynapseEnvironment.java:569)
> [synapse-core_2.1.7.wso2v227.jar:2.1.7-wso2v227]  at
> org.apache.synapse.mediators.builtin.SendMediator.mediate(SendMediator.java:120)
> [synapse-core_2.1.7.wso2v227.jar:2.1.7-wso2v227]  at
> org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:109)
> [synapse-core_2.1.7.wso2v227.jar:2.1.7-wso2v227]  at
> org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:71)
> [synapse-core_2.1.7.wso2v227.jar:2.1.7-wso2v227]  at
> org.apache.synapse.mediators.base.SequenceMediator.mediate(SequenceMediator.java:158)
> [synapse-core_2.1.7.wso2v227.jar:2.1.7-wso2v227]  at
> org.apache.synapse.api.Resource.process(Resource.java:342)
> [synapse-core_2.1.7.wso2v227.jar:2.1.7-wso2v227]  at
> org.apache.synapse.api.API.process(API.java:402)
> [synapse-core_2.1.7.wso2v227.jar:2.1.7-wso2v227]  at
> org.apache.synapse.api.AbstractApiHandler.apiProcessNonDefaultStrategy(AbstractApiHandler.java:107)
> [synapse-core_2.1.7.wso2v227.jar:2.1.7-wso2v227]  at
> org.apache.synapse.api.AbstractApiHandler.identifyAPI(AbstractApiHandler.java:127)
> [synapse-core_2.1.7.wso2v227.jar:2.1.7-wso2v227]  at
> org.apache.synapse.api.AbstractApiHandler.dispatchToAPI(AbstractApiHandler.java:54)
> [synapse-core_2.1.7.wso2v227.jar:2.1.7-wso2v227]  at
> org.apache.synapse.api.rest.RestRequestHandler.dispatchToAPI(RestRequestHandler.java:84)
> [synapse-core_2.1.7.wso2v227.jar:2.1.7-wso2v227]  at
> org.apache.synapse.api.rest.RestRequestHandler.process(RestRequestHandler.java:57)
> [synapse-core_2.1.7.wso2v227.jar:2.1.7-wso2v227]  at
> org.apache.synapse.rest.RESTRequestHandler.process(RESTRequestHandler.java:54)
> [synapse-core_2.1.7.wso2v227.jar:2.1.7-wso2v227]  at
> org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2SynapseEnvironment.injectMessage(Axis2SynapseEnvironment.java:344)
> [synapse-core_2.1.7.wso2v227.jar:2.1.7-wso2v227]  at
> org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.SynapseCallbackReceiver.handleMessage(SynapseCallbackReceiver.java:608)
> [synapse-core_2.1.7.wso2v227.jar:2.1.7-wso2v227]  at
> org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.SynapseCallbackReceiver.receive(SynapseCallbackReceiver.java:207)
> [synapse-core_2.1.7.wso2v227.jar:2.1.7-wso2v227]  at
> org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:180)
> [axis2_1.6.1.wso2v63.jar:?]   at
> org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ClientWorker.run(ClientWorker.java:298)
> [synapse-nhttp-transport_2.1.7.wso2v227.jar:?]    at
> org.apache.axis2.transport.base.threads.NativeWorkerPool$1.run(NativeWorkerPool.java:172)
> [axis2_1.6.1.wso2v63.jar:?]   at
> java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
> [?:?]     at
> java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
> [?:?]     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834) [?:?] Caused by:
> org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: Could not write JSON stream.  at
> org.apache.synapse.commons.json.JsonUtil.writeJsonStream(JsonUtil.java:1226)
> ~[synapse-commons_2.1.7.wso2v227.jar:?]   at
> org.apache.synapse.commons.json.JsonUtil.writeAsJson(JsonUtil.java:388)
> ~[synapse-commons_2.1.7.wso2v227.jar:?]   ... 28 more Caused by:
> java.io.IOException: Consumer error or stale connection has occurred.
> at
> org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.Pipe$ByteBufferOutputStream.write(Pipe.java:647)
> ~[synapse-nhttp-transport_2.1.7.wso2v227.jar:?]   at
> java.util.zip.DeflaterOutputStream.deflate(DeflaterOutputStream.java:253)
> ~[?:?]    at
> java.util.zip.DeflaterOutputStream.write(DeflaterOutputStream.java:211)
> ~[?:?]    at
> java.util.zip.GZIPOutputStream.write(GZIPOutputStream.java:146) ~[?:?]
> at org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.copyLarge(IOUtils.java:1793)
> ~[commons-io_2.4.0.wso2v1.jar:?]  at
> org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.copyLarge(IOUtils.java:1769)
> ~[commons-io_2.4.0.wso2v1.jar:?]  at
> org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.copy(IOUtils.java:1744)
> ~[commons-io_2.4.0.wso2v1.jar:?]  at
> org.apache.synapse.commons.json.JsonUtil.writeJsonStream(JsonUtil.java:1202)
> ~[synapse-commons_2.1.7.wso2v227.jar:?]   at
> org.apache.synapse.commons.json.JsonUtil.writeAsJson(JsonUtil.java:388)
> ~[synapse-commons_2.1.7.wso2v227.jar:?]
> ... 28 more
>
> 2023-01-20T00:05:54,568 [-] [PassThroughMessageProcessor-138] ERROR
> PassThroughHttpSSLSender Failed to submit the response
> org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: Error getting GZIP output stream  at
> org.apache.synapse.transport.nhttp.util.GzipMessageFormatterDecorator.handleException(GzipMessageFormatterDecorator.java:95)
> ~[synapse-nhttp-transport_2.1.7.wso2v227.jar:?]   at
> org.apache.synapse.transport.nhttp.util.GzipMessageFormatterDecorator.writeTo(GzipMessageFormatterDecorator.java:76)
> ~[synapse-nhttp-transport_2.1.7.wso2v227.jar:?]   at
> org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.PassThroughHttpSender.submitResponse(PassThroughHttpSender.java:594)
> [synapse-nhttp-transport_2.1.7.wso2v227.jar:?]    at
> org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.PassThroughHttpSender.invoke(PassThroughHttpSender.java:290)
> [synapse-nhttp-transport_2.1.7.wso2v227.jar:?]    at
> org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.send(AxisEngine.java:442)
> [axis2_1.6.1.wso2v63.jar:?]   at
> org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2Sender.sendBack(Axis2Sender.java:213)
> [synapse-core_2.1.7.wso2v227.jar:2.1.7-wso2v227]  at
> org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2SynapseEnvironment.send(Axis2SynapseEnvironment.java:569)
> [synapse-core_2.1.7.wso2v227.jar:2.1.7-wso2v227]  at
> org.apache.synapse.mediators.builtin.SendMediator.mediate(SendMediator.java:120)
> [synapse-core_2.1.7.wso2v227.jar:2.1.7-wso2v227]  at
> org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:109)
> [synapse-core_2.1.7.wso2v227.jar:2.1.7-wso2v227]  at
> org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:71)
> [synapse-core_2.1.7.wso2v227.jar:2.1.7-wso2v227]  at
> org.apache.synapse.mediators.base.SequenceMediator.mediate(SequenceMediator.java:158)
> [synapse-core_2.1.7.wso2v227.jar:2.1.7-wso2v227]  at
> org.apache.synapse.api.Resource.process(Resource.java:342)
> [synapse-core_2.1.7.wso2v227.jar:2.1.7-wso2v227]  at
> org.apache.synapse.api.API.process(API.java:402)
> [synapse-core_2.1.7.wso2v227.jar:2.1.7-wso2v227]  at
> org.apache.synapse.api.AbstractApiHandler.apiProcessNonDefaultStrategy(AbstractApiHandler.java:107)
> [synapse-core_2.1.7.wso2v227.jar:2.1.7-wso2v227]  at
> org.apache.synapse.api.AbstractApiHandler.identifyAPI(AbstractApiHandler.java:127)
> [synapse-core_2.1.7.wso2v227.jar:2.1.7-wso2v227]  at
> org.apache.synapse.api.AbstractApiHandler.dispatchToAPI(AbstractApiHandler.java:54)
> [synapse-core_2.1.7.wso2v227.jar:2.1.7-wso2v227]  at
> org.apache.synapse.api.rest.RestRequestHandler.dispatchToAPI(RestRequestHandler.java:84)
> [synapse-core_2.1.7.wso2v227.jar:2.1.7-wso2v227]  at
> org.apache.synapse.api.rest.RestRequestHandler.process(RestRequestHandler.java:57)
> [synapse-core_2.1.7.wso2v227.jar:2.1.7-wso2v227]  at
> org.apache.synapse.rest.RESTRequestHandler.process(RESTRequestHandler.java:54)
> [synapse-core_2.1.7.wso2v227.jar:2.1.7-wso2v227]  at
> org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2SynapseEnvironment.injectMessage(Axis2SynapseEnvironment.java:344)
> [synapse-core_2.1.7.wso2v227.jar:2.1.7-wso2v227]  at
> ... very long
> org.apache.axis2.transport.base.threads.NativeWorkerPool$1.run(NativeWorkerPool.java:172)
> [axis2_1.6.1.wso2v63.jar:?]   at
> java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
> [?:?]     at
> java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
> [?:?]     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834) [?:?] Caused by:
> org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: Could not write JSON stream.  at
> org.apache.synapse.commons.json.JsonUtil.writeAsJson(JsonUtil.java:400)
> ~[synapse-commons_2.1.7.wso2v227.jar:?]   at
> org.apache.synapse.commons.json.JsonStreamFormatter.writeTo(JsonStreamFormatter.java:77)
> ~[synapse-commons_2.1.7.wso2v227.jar:?]   at
> org.apache.synapse.transport.nhttp.util.GzipMessageFormatterDecorator.writeTo(GzipMessageFormatterDecorator.java:66)
> ~[synapse-nhttp-transport_2.1.7.wso2v227.jar:?]   ... 26 more Caused
> by: org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: Could not write JSON stream.  at
> org.apache.synapse.commons.json.JsonUtil.writeJsonStream(JsonUtil.java:1226)
> ~[synapse-commons_2.1.7.wso2v227.jar:?]   at
> org.apache.synapse.commons.json.JsonUtil.writeAsJson(JsonUtil.java:388)
> ~[synapse-commons_2.1.7.wso2v227.jar:?]   at
> org.apache.synapse.commons.json.JsonStreamFormatter.writeTo(JsonStreamFormatter.java:77)
> ~[synapse-commons_2.1.7.wso2v227.jar:?]   at
> org.apache.synapse.transport.nhttp.util.GzipMessageFormatterDecorator.writeTo(GzipMessageFormatterDecorator.java:66)
> ~[synapse-nhttp-transport_2.1.7.wso2v227.jar:?]   ... 26 more Caused
> by: java.io.IOException: Consumer error or stale connection has
> occurred.     at
> org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.Pipe$ByteBufferOutputStream.write(Pipe.java:647)
> ~[synapse-nhttp-transport_2.1.7.wso2v227.jar:?]   at
> java.util.zip.DeflaterOutputStream.deflate(DeflaterOutputStream.java:253)
> ~[?:?]    at
> java.util.zip.DeflaterOutputStream.write(DeflaterOutputStream.java:211)
> ~[?:?]    at
> java.util.zip.GZIPOutputStream.write(GZIPOutputStream.java:146) ~[?:?]
> at org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.copyLarge(IOUtils.java:1793)
> ~[commons-io_2.4.0.wso2v1.jar:?]  at
> org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.copyLarge(IOUtils.java:1769)
> ~[commons-io_2.4.0.wso2v1.jar:?]  at
> org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.copy(IOUtils.java:1744)
> ~[commons-io_2.4.0.wso2v1.jar:?]  at
> org.apache.synapse.commons.json.JsonUtil.writeJsonStream(JsonUtil.java:1202)
> ~[synapse-commons_2.1.7.wso2v227.jar:?]   at
> org.apache.synapse.commons.json.JsonUtil.writeAsJson(JsonUtil.java:388)
> ~[synapse-commons_2.1.7.wso2v227.jar:?]   at
> org.apache.synapse.commons.json.JsonStreamFormatter.writeTo(JsonStreamFormatter.java:77)
> ~[synapse-commons_2.1.7.wso2v227.jar:?]   at
> org.apache.synapse.transport.nhttp.util.GzipMessageFormatterDecorator.writeTo(GzipMessageFormatterDecorator.java:66)
> ~[synapse-nhttp-transport_2.1.7.wso2v227.jar:?]   ... 26 more
>
> 2023-01-20T00:05:54,569 [-] [PassThroughMessageProcessor-138] ERROR
> Axis2Sender {api:myApi:vv2}
> Access-Control-Allow-Headers:authorization,Access-Control-Allow-Origin,Content-Type,SOAPAction,apikey,Authorization,Access-Control-Allow-Methods:GET,Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*,Access-Control-Expose-Headers:,activityid:2afa5a65-a159-47ec-86da-8b63c984b78c,cacheKey:90-6911153-3753-724507227482819-49,Content-Encoding:gzip,Content-Type:application/json,expires:-1,messageType:application/json,pragma:no-cache,Strict-Transport-Security:max-age=63072000,Vary:Accept-Encoding,X-Cache:EXPIRED,
> Unexpected error sending message back org.apache.axis2.AxisFault:
> Failed to submit the response     at
> org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.PassThroughHttpSender.handleException(PassThroughHttpSender.java:656)
> ~[synapse-nhttp-transport_2.1.7.wso2v227.jar:?]   at
> org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.PassThroughHttpSender.invoke(PassThroughHttpSender.java:292)
> ~[synapse-nhttp-transport_2.1.7.wso2v227.jar:?]   at
> org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.send(AxisEngine.java:442)
> ~[axis2_1.6.1.wso2v63.jar:?]  at
> org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2Sender.sendBack(Axis2Sender.java:213)
> [synapse-core_2.1.7.wso2v227.jar:2.1.7-wso2v227]  at
> org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2SynapseEnvironment.send(Axis2SynapseEnvironment.java:569)
> [synapse-core_2.1.7.wso2v227.jar:2.1.7-wso2v227]  at
> org.apache.synapse.mediators.builtin.SendMediator.mediate(SendMediator.java:120)
> ... very long
> [?:?]     at
> java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
> [?:?]     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834) [?:?] Caused by:
> org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: Error getting GZIP output stream  at
> org.apache.synapse.transport.nhttp.util.GzipMessageFormatterDecorator.handleException(GzipMessageFormatterDecorator.java:95)
> ~[synapse-nhttp-transport_2.1.7.wso2v227.jar:?]   at
> org.apache.synapse.transport.nhttp.util.GzipMessageFormatterDecorator.writeTo(GzipMessageFormatterDecorator.java:76)
> ~[synapse-nhttp-transport_2.1.7.wso2v227.jar:?]   at
> org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.PassThroughHttpSender.submitResponse(PassThroughHttpSender.java:594)
> ~[synapse-nhttp-transport_2.1.7.wso2v227.jar:?]   at
> org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.PassThroughHttpSender.invoke(PassThroughHttpSender.java:290)
> ~[synapse-nhttp-transport_2.1.7.wso2v227.jar:?]   ... 24 more Caused
> by: org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: Could not write JSON stream.  at
> org.apache.synapse.commons.json.JsonUtil.writeAsJson(JsonUtil.java:400)
> ~[synapse-commons_2.1.7.wso2v227.jar:?]   at
> org.apache.synapse.commons.json.JsonStreamFormatter.writeTo(JsonStreamFormatter.java:77)
> ~[synapse-commons_2.1.7.wso2v227.jar:?]   at
> org.apache.synapse.transport.nhttp.util.GzipMessageFormatterDecorator.writeTo(GzipMessageFormatterDecorator.java:66)
> ~[synapse-nhttp-transport_2.1.7.wso2v227.jar:?]   at
> org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.PassThroughHttpSender.submitResponse(PassThroughHttpSender.java:594)
> ~[synapse-nhttp-transport_2.1.7.wso2v227.jar:?]   at
> org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.PassThroughHttpSender.invoke(PassThroughHttpSender.java:290)
> ~[synapse-nhttp-transport_2.1.7.wso2v227.jar:?]   ... 24 more Caused
> by: org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: Could not write JSON stream.  at
> org.apache.synapse.commons.json.JsonUtil.writeJsonStream(JsonUtil.java:1226)
> ~[synapse-commons_2.1.7.wso2v227.jar:?]   at
> org.apache.synapse.commons.json.JsonUtil.writeAsJson(JsonUtil.java:388)
> ~[synapse-commons_2.1.7.wso2v227.jar:?]   at
> org.apache.synapse.commons.json.JsonStreamFormatter.writeTo(JsonStreamFormatter.java:77)
> ~[synapse-commons_2.1.7.wso2v227.jar:?]   at
> org.apache.synapse.transport.nhttp.util.GzipMessageFormatterDecorator.writeTo(GzipMessageFormatterDecorator.java:66)
> ~[synapse-nhttp-transport_2.1.7.wso2v227.jar:?]   at
> org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.PassThroughHttpSender.submitResponse(PassThroughHttpSender.java:594)
> ~[synapse-nhttp-transport_2.1.7.wso2v227.jar:?]   at
> org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.PassThroughHttpSender.invoke(PassThroughHttpSender.java:290)
> ~[synapse-nhttp-transport_2.1.7.wso2v227.jar:?]   ... 24 more Caused
> by: java.io.IOException: Consumer error or stale connection has
> occurred.     at
> org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.Pipe$ByteBufferOutputStream.write(Pipe.java:647)
> ~[synapse-nhttp-transport_2.1.7.wso2v227.jar:?]   at
> java.util.zip.DeflaterOutputStream.deflate(DeflaterOutputStream.java:253)
> ~[?:?]    at
> java.util.zip.DeflaterOutputStream.write(DeflaterOutputStream.java:211)
> ~[?:?]    at
> java.util.zip.GZIPOutputStream.write(GZIPOutputStream.java:146) ~[?:?]
> at org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.copyLarge(IOUtils.java:1793)
> ~[commons-io_2.4.0.wso2v1.jar:?]  at
> org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.copyLarge(IOUtils.java:1769)
> ~[commons-io_2.4.0.wso2v1.jar:?]  at
> org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.copy(IOUtils.java:1744)
> ~[commons-io_2.4.0.wso2v1.jar:?]  at
> org.apache.synapse.commons.json.JsonUtil.writeJsonStream(JsonUtil.java:1202)
> ~[synapse-commons_2.1.7.wso2v227.jar:?]   at
> org.apache.synapse.commons.json.JsonUtil.writeAsJson(JsonUtil.java:388)
> ~[synapse-commons_2.1.7.wso2v227.jar:?]   at
> org.apache.synapse.commons.json.JsonStreamFormatter.writeTo(JsonStreamFormatter.java:77)
> ~[synapse-commons_2.1.7.wso2v227.jar:?]   at
> org.apache.synapse.transport.nhttp.util.GzipMessageFormatterDecorator.writeTo(GzipMessageFormatterDecorator.java:66)
> ~[synapse-nhttp-transport_2.1.7.wso2v227.jar:?]   at
> org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.PassThroughHttpSender.submitResponse(PassThroughHttpSender.java:594)
> ~[synapse-nhttp-transport_2.1.7.wso2v227.jar:?]   at
> org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.PassThroughHttpSender.invoke(PassThroughHttpSender.java:290)
> ~[synapse-nhttp-transport_2.1.7.wso2v227.jar:?]   ... 24 more
>
> 2023-01-20T00:05:54,696 [-] [PassThroughMessageProcessor-138]  WARN Axis2Sender Trying to send a response to an already responded client request - Rest API Context : /my/api

**Is WSO2 struggling with Gzip ? Or maybe a misconfig on Nginx ?**

**reverse nginx custom params :**

```
sendfile                      on;
tcp_nopush                    on;
tcp_nodelay                   on;
server_tokens                 off;
client_max_body_size          4M;
server_names_hash_bucket_size 128;
keepalive_timeout             65;
keepalive_disable             msie6;
keepalive_requests            100;
types_hash_max_size           2048;

gzip              on;
gzip_comp_level   6;
gzip_min_length   512;
gzip_buffers      32 16k;
gzip_http_version 1.1;
gzip_proxied      any;
gzip_vary         on;
gzip_disable      "msie6";
gzip_types        text/css
                  text/javascript
                  text/xml
                  text/plain
                  text/x-component
                  application/javascript
                  application/x-javascript
                  application/json
                  application/xml
                  application/rss+xml
                  application/vnd.ms-fontobject
                  font/truetype
                  font/opentype
                  image/svg+xml;
```

**reverse apim-gw vhost :**

```
upstream apim {

    server 192.168.0.5:8243;
    keepalive 32;

}

server {

    # Listen
    server_name apim.mysite.com;
    listen      443      ssl http2;
    listen      [::]:443 ssl http2;

    # Certs
    ssl_certificate     /home/user/certs/mysite.com.fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /home/user/certs/mysite.com.privkey.key;

    # Proxy conf
    location / {
        proxy_pass              https://apim;
        proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Host   $host;
        proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Server $host;
        proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For    $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header        Host               $http_host;
        proxy_set_header        Connection         "";
        proxy_connect_timeout   90s;
        proxy_send_timeout      90s;
        proxy_read_timeout      90s;
    }

}
```

**apim-bo /etc/hosts :**

```
127.0.1.1 apimbo.mysite.com
127.0.0.1 localhost
192.168.0.5 apim.mysite.com
```

**apim-bo deployment.toml :**

```
[server]
hostname = "apimbo.mysite.com"
base_path = "${carbon.protocol}://${carbon.host}:${carbon.management.port}"
server_role = "control-plane"

[super_admin]
username = "admin"
password = "adminpass"
create_admin_account = true

[user_store]
type = "database_unique_id"

[database.apim_db]
type = "mysql"
hostname = "192.168.0.4"
name = "apimdb"
port = "3306"
username = "apimdbuser"
password = "apimdbpass"
driver = "com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver"

[database.shared_db]
type = "mysql"
hostname = "192.168.0.4"
name = "apimshareddb"
port = "3306"
username = "apimshareddbuser"
password = "apimshareddbpass"
driver = "com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver"

[keystore.tls]
file_name = "wso2carbon.jks"
type = "PKCS12"
password = "wso2"
alias = "apim"
key_password = "wso2"

[keystore.primary]
file_name = "wso2carbon.jks"
type = "{{ wso2_keystore_type }}"
password = "{{ wso2_keystore_new_password }}"
alias = "{{ wso2_keystore_new_alias }}"
key_password = "{{ wso2_keystore_new_password }}"

[keystore.internal]
file_name = "wso2carbon.jks"
type = "PKCS12"
password = "{{ wso2_keystore_new_password }}"
alias = "{{ wso2_keystore_new_alias }}"
key_password = "{{ wso2_keystore_new_password }}"

[truststore]
file_name = "client-truststore.jks"
type = "PKCS12"
password = "wso2"
alias = "symmetric.key.value"
algorithm = "AES"

# Custom : apim gateway env
[[apim.gateway.environment]]
name = "Default"
type = "hybrid"
display_in_api_console = true
description = "This is a hybrid gateway that handles both production and sandbox token traffic."
show_as_token_endpoint_url = true
service_url = "https://apim.mysite.com/services/"
username= "${admin.username}"
password= "${admin.password}"
ws_endpoint = "ws://apim.mysite.com:9099"
wss_endpoint = "wss://apim.mysite.com:8099"
http_endpoint = "http://apim.mysite.com"
https_endpoint = "https://apim.mysite.com"

[apim.cache.tags]
expiry_time = "2m"

[apim.cache.jwt_claim]
enable = true

[apim.cache.gateway_token]
enable = true

[apim.cache.resource]
enable = true

[apim.cache.km_token]
enable = true

[apim.cache.scopes]
enable = true

[apim.oauth_config]
revoke_endpoint = "https://apimbo.mysite.com/oauth2/revoke"

[apim.devportal]
url = "https://apimbo.mysite.com/devportal"
api_key_alias = "apim"
display_multiple_versions = true

[apim.cors]
allow_origins = "*"
allow_methods = ["GET","PUT","POST","DELETE","PATCH","OPTIONS"]
allow_headers = ["authorization","Access-Control-Allow-Origin","Content-Type","SOAPAction", "apikey","Internal-Key"]
allow_credentials = false

[apim.workflow]
token_endpoint = "https://apimbo.mysite.com/oauth2/token"

[apim.notification]
hostname = "apimbo.mysite.com"

[[event_handler]]
name="userPostSelfRegistration"
subscriptions=["POST_ADD_USER"]

[service_provider]
sp_name_regex = "^[\\sa-zA-Z0-9._-]*$"

[database.local]
url = "jdbc:h2:./repository/database/WSO2CARBON_DB;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE"

[[event_listener]]
id = "token_revocation"
type = "org.wso2.carbon.identity.core.handler.AbstractIdentityHandler"
name = "org.wso2.is.notification.ApimOauthEventInterceptor"
order = 1
[event_listener.properties]
notification_endpoint = "https://localhost:${mgt.transport.https.port}/internal/data/v1/notify"
username = "${admin.username}"
password = "${admin.password}"
'header.X-WSO2-KEY-MANAGER' = "default"

[transport.https.properties]
proxyPort = 443
```

**apim-gw /etc/hosts :**

```
127.0.1.1 apim.mysite.com
127.0.0.1 localhost
192.168.0.6 apimbo.mysite.com
```

**apim-gw deployment.toml :**

```
[server]
hostname = "apim.mysite.com"
server_role = "gateway-worker"

[super_admin]
username = "admin"
password = "adminpass"
create_admin_account = true

[user_store]
type = "database_unique_id"

[database.shared_db]
type = "mysql"
hostname = "192.168.0.4"
name = "apimshareddb"
port = "3306"
username = "apimshareddbname"
password = "apimshareddbpass"
driver = "com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver"

[keystore.tls]
file_name = "wso2carbon.jks"
type = "PKCS12"
password = "wso2"
alias = "apim"
key_password = "wso2"

[keystore.primary]
file_name = "wso2carbon.jks"
type = "PKCS12"
password = "wso2"
alias = "apim"
key_password = "wso2"

[keystore.internal]
file_name = "wso2carbon.jks"
type = "PKCS12"
password = "wso2"
alias = "apim"
key_password = "wso2"

[truststore]
file_name = "client-truststore.jks"
type = "PKCS12"
password = "wso2"
alias = "symmetric.key.value"
algorithm = "AES"

[apim.key_manager]
service_url = "https://apimbo.mysite.com:9443${carbon.context}/services/"
username= "$ref{super_admin.username}"
password= "$ref{super_admin.password}"

[apim.jwt]
enable = true
encoding = "base64"
claim_dialect = "http://wso2.org/claims"
header = "X-JWT-Assertion"
signing_algorithm = "SHA256withRSA"

[apim.sync_runtime_artifacts.gateway]
gateway_labels = ["Default"]

[apim.throttling]
service_url = "https://apimbo.mysite.com:9443/services/"
username = "$ref{super_admin.username}"
password = "$ref{super_admin.password}"
enable_unlimited_tier = true
enable_header_based_throttling = false
enable_jwt_claim_based_throttling = false
enable_query_param_based_throttling = false
throttle_decision_endpoints = ["tcp://apimbo.mysite.com:5672","tcp://apimbo.mysite.com:5672"]

[[apim.throttling.url_group]]
traffic_manager_urls=["tcp://apimbo.mysite.com:9611"]
traffic_manager_auth_urls=["ssl://apimbo.mysite.com:9711"]

[apim.analytics]
enable = false
config_endpoint = "https://analytics-event-auth.choreo.dev/auth/v1"
auth_token = "ffffffff-ffff-ffff-ffff-ffffffffffff"

[apim.cache.jwt_claim]
enable = true
expiry_time = 900

[apim.cache.gateway_token]
enable = true
expiry_time = 15

[apim.cache.resource]
enable = true

[apim.cache.km_token]
enable = true

[apim.oauth_config]
remove_outbound_auth_header = true
auth_header = "Authorization"

[apim.devportal]
api_key_alias = "apim"

[apim.cors]
allow_origins = "*"
allow_methods = ["GET","PUT","POST","DELETE","PATCH","OPTIONS"]
allow_headers = ["authorization","Access-Control-Allow-Origin","Content-Type","SOAPAction", "apikey"]
allow_credentials = false

[transport.http]
properties.port = 9763
properties.proxyPort = 80

[transport.https]
properties.port = 9443
properties.proxyPort = 443

[passthru_http]
worker_thread_keepalive_sec = 60
worker_pool_queue_length = -1
core_worker_pool_size = 400
max_worker_pool_size = 400
io_buffer_size = 16384
http.socket.timeout = 180000

[message_builder]
json = "org.apache.synapse.commons.json.JsonStreamBuilder"
```

Comment: Can you check your backend latency? Seems like these are due to connections being closed from the client side.

Comment: Thanks and sorry for the very long answer. Yes this is a normal behavior, there are mobile clients that sometomes close the connexion before the backend could answer.